# Column vertical alignment in twocolumn mode

Tags: vertical-alignment, two-column

I would like to achieve a column alignment in `twocolumn` (note: I need to place many pictures so `multicol` environment is not an option) and place the letters directly after aligned two column text. The ME differs from this [correct answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222760/8380) in not setting the letters on the next page.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{extbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

 \newcommand*{\dictchar}[1]{
 %\clearpage
 \centerline{\parbox[c][3cm][c]{2cm}{%
 \fontsize{24}{24}
 \selectfont
 {#1}}}\par
 }

 % DICTIONARY PAGE STYLE
\fancypagestyle{dictstyle}{%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont{\textbf{\rightmark}}}}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\thepage}%the page numbers will be printed when the dictionary is ready
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont{\textbf{\leftmark}}}}}

% middle rule  
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.1pt}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn
\pagestyle{dictstyle}

\dictchar{E e}

\lipsum[1-1]

\dictchar{F f}
\lipsum[1-2]

\dictchar{G g}
\lipsum[3-20]

\end{document}
```

In other words I would like to typeset this:

[image: Example of letter P]

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want to reduce the vertical spacing before and after your `\dictchar`-macro content?

Comment: So you want to switch to `onecolumn` mode in between?

Comment: Yes, actually. But it envolves no pagebreak and the alignment of the rest of the headwords from the previous letter (in the picture is shown how headwords starting with O aligns, ozonometer is the last headword).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `cuted` package and it's `strip` environment provide the desired feature. (I reduced the height of the parbox however, since `cuted` seems to add a lot of vertical space.)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{extbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{cuted}


\newcommand{\dictchar}[1]{%
\begin{strip}
 \centering
 \parbox[c][1cm][c]{2cm}{%
   \centering
      \fontsize{24}{24}
      \selectfont
      {#1}%
}
\end{strip}
}

 % DICTIONARY PAGE STYLE
\fancypagestyle{dictstyle}{%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont{\textbf{\rightmark}}}}
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\thepage}%the page numbers will be printed when the dictionary is ready
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont{\textbf{\leftmark}}}}}

% middle rule  
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.1pt}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{dictstyle}

\dictchar{E e}
\lipsum[2]

\dictchar{F f}
\lipsum[1-2]

\dictchar{G g}
\lipsum[3-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is correct and answer to my question. Unfortunately pictures cause wrong placement. I should probably start new question.

Comment: There's a continuation of this question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/223050/8380)